# How do I get the "{slice}/{action}" value of an action from my component?

Tags: redux-toolkit

I have some logic in my component that needs to know the string value of some of my actions.  That's the value that shows in the redux toolkit and looks like {slice name}/{action}.  Is there a ncie way to do this?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `createSlice` and exporting the actions from it, `createAction`, or `createAsyncThunk`, you can reference the `.type` property to get this value.

Example:

```js
import React from "react";
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const slice = createSlice({
  name: "test",
  initialState: { value: 0 },
  reducers: {
    increment: (state, action) => {
      state.value += action.payload;
    }
  }
});

export const { increment } = slice.actions;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Action name: {increment.type}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```